# Does .focus() work on elements not present in the DOM on pageload?

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I have this jQuery code:

```
$('.triggermodal').focus(function(event) {
    $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    $('.focusme').focus();
});
```

It's supposed to open a modal (using the Foundation framework) and then direct the browser's focus to an input field within that modal. For some reason it won't direct the focus, and the only thing I can think of is the possibility that .focus() will only work on elements present on pageload. The jQuery docs don't make any mention of this (that I can find).

If I replace .focus() with .addClass("hidden") a class of .hidden does indeed appear on .focusme, so it seems there's something specifically wrong with .focus().

Any advice appreciated. If I've left out some crucial information, let me know!

Comment: you have to wait for the `foundation` process to finish.

Comment: How do I go about that? I'm relatively new to jQuery.

Comment: `.on` is what you are looking for - check out the jQuery docs on it and in 99% of cases use it over .click .focus etc. (unless building a massive application - but if you are at that stage you will know why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen when the modal is [ready](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html), and then do the focus:

```
$(document).on('opened.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
  if( $(this).id == "myModal" ){
    $('.focusme').focus();
  }
});
```

Comment: Ha! I had checked the Zurb docs, but it turns out I was looking at the documentation for a previous version. Thanks a lot, that sorted it out.